# PostgreSQL could not open file "base/xxxx/xxxxx" no such file or directory

Tags: linux, postgresql

Recently I had a Hardware failure on my linux machine and after fixing hardware problem and bringing back my linux machine up, when I execute query against one of my table, following error is returned.

```
ERROR: could not open file "base/17085/281016": No such file or directory.
```

When checked in postgresql/base/17085 directory, file 281016 does not exist.

Would the issue be resolved if I create file manually by using below commands? or is it a bad approach causing more troubles in future?

```
#touch 281016
#chown postgres:postgres 281016
#chmod 600 281016
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: restore from backup. Then investigate your setup, you are running an unsafe system.

Long answer:

Assuming you don't have a backup but need the database you have learnt a valuable lesson. Take and check your backups.

If it's a simple `SELECT * FROM bad_table` that's failing then it's the table that has the problem. If not, `COPY` the data out immediately, you've been lucky and it's just an index that got destroyed.

Then dump all the rest of your tables.

Then do some checks to make sure the data is in a sane state before restoring it and putting it back in production.

Now - barring bugs in PostgreSQL (unlikely) this should be impossible. Since we are talking about a missing file I would guess your disks are reporting data is [flushed and synced](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-reliability.html) when it really isn't. Check your [fsync](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FSYNC) settings in postgresql.conf anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Richard :)
This is my test system, not much of data here and agree with you restoring from backup would be best option.

Just curious to know if we can create missing files manually if such issue arises and can be impacts for such procedure?

Comment: You can create an empty file, but your database is corrupted then. Sometimes it can be useful to fill corrupted disk blocks with zeroes or extend a file likewise. Then you can dump around the damaged parts to recover as much as you can. If it's not worth a *lot* of effort, you are better off restoring from the last backup and writing off any updates.

Answer (score 0):

In my local server, it was an issue with one of my test databases, just drop this database. It is ok now. For prodution server isn't a good idea droping database.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem running vacuum on Postgres 12.**

This database is production, but fortunately not customer-facing.  It does track storage details for 3 large Isilon clusters that are important and I needed to recover it.  This is what fixed my system.

After seeing errors:

```
database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database ((database_2_name)) 

HINT: Stop the postmaster and vacuum that database in single-user mode. You might also need to commit or roll back prepared transactions, or drop stale replication slots.
```

I stopped the postmaster (CentOS7 + Systemd)

```
systemctl stop postgresql-12.service
```

Then started postgres in single user mode:

```
# su - postgres
postgres --single -D /var/cache/insightiq/pgsql/data  ((database_1_name))
```

The database kicks out a little warning:

```
> WARNING:  database with OID 16403 must be vacuumed within 990276 transactions
> HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a database-wide VACUUM in that database.
         You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions, or drop stale replication slots.

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 12.4
backend>
```

Then attempting the vacuum, but ran into the missing *number?* under my database's OID (16403).  I noticed this 16403 was associated at the top level of the storage set up for my ((database_1_name))

```
backend> vacuum

<2023-01-05 19:00:41.150 UTC [4229] > ERROR:  could not open file "base/16403/2613": No such file or directory
<2023-01-05 19:00:41.150 UTC [4229] > STATEMENT:  vacuum
```

As the original poster suggested I did attempt to add a file at the location (where the data should be), but there was no change in the error when I tried vacuum again.  The same 'could not open file "base/16403/2613"'

In my case, my large database structures are off on NFS nad I could see them changing when I ran vacuum.  I searched my local filesystem for anything named 'base/16403' and found a directory structure where the data was not expected to be, in /var/cache/insightiq/pgsql/data/base/16403.

With no other choice I decided to **GAMBLE!** I created an empty file in the location `vacuum` was complaining about (cache location instead of data location)

```
# ls /var/cache/insightiq/pgsql/data/base/16403/2613
ls: cannot access /var/cache/insightiq/pgsql/data/base/16403/2613: No such file or directory
# touch /var/cache/insightiq/pgsql/data/base/16403/2613
# chown postgres:postgres /var/cache/insightiq/pgsql/data/base/16403/2613
```

Presto.  Single-user `vacuum` works on my database.  The vacuum recommended doing the same on the other databases, which went smoothly.  At the end, I stop/started everything and this System is working again.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be triggered by procedural language functions changing the current directory, without PostgreSQL already having an open handle to the file in question. Consider the following example:

```
DROP DATABASE customer;
CREATE DATABASE customer;
\c customer
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
CREATE SEQUENCE customer_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE customer(
    id int NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('customer_id_seq'),
    name varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE item_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE item(
    id int NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('item_id_seq'),
    name varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v__new_customer
AS
SELECT 'Name'::varchar AS customer_name;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f__new_customer(
    customer_name varchar
) RETURNS customer
AS
$BODY$
    if (!chdir('/')) {
        elog(ERROR, 'chdir(): /: $!");
        return undef;
    }
    return { name => 'Just a test' };
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plperlu' VOLATILE SECURITY INVOKER;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE r__new_customer
AS
ON INSERT TO v__new_customer
DO INSTEAD
SELECT f__new_customer(NEW.customer_name);
```

Now try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM customer; -- Works, directory not changed yet.

INSERT INTO v__new_customer (customer_name) VALUES ('LOVE_CO2');

SELECT * FROM customer; -- Still works, the database already has a handle for the file backing this relation.

SELECT * FROM item; -- Fails with: 'ERROR:  could not open file "base/12345/12345": No such file or directory' - the database didn't already have a handle for the file backing this relation.
```

The solution is rather simple, just do a chdir() (or equivalent depending on the language you're developing in) back to the directory you started in. (/var/lib/postgresql/15/data or similar.)

Hope it helps anyone developing procedural language functions.