# PostgreSQL ERROR: could not open file "base/.../..."

Tags: linux, postgresql

There are many queue_promotion_n tables where n is from 1 to 100.
There is an error on the 73 table with a fairly simple query

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT queue_id)
FROM "queue_promotion_73"
WHERE status_new > NOW() - interval '3 days';
```

> ERROR:  could not open file "base/16387/357386324.1" (target block
>   200005): No such file or directory

Uptime DB 23 days. How to fix it?

Comment: Looks like data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that you have up-to-date backups (or verify that your DB replica is in sync)
2. [PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) recommends stopping DB and `rsync` whole all PostgreSQL files to a safe location.

File where the table is physically stored seems to be missing. You can check where PostgreSQL stores data on disk using:

```
SELECT pg_relation_filepath('queue_promotion_73');
 pg_relation_filepath 
----------------------
 base/16387/357386324
(1 row)
```

If you are sure that your hard drives/RAID controller works fine, you can try rebuilding the table. It is a good idea to try this on a replica or backup snapshot of the database first.

```
VACUUM FULL queue_promotion_73;
```

Check again the relation path:

```
SELECT pg_relation_filepath('queue_promotion_73');
```

it should be different and hopefully with all required files.

The cause could be related to a hardware issue, make sure to check DB consistency.

Answer (score 0):

The OPs SQL doesn't seem to include any calls to any custom procedural language functions, so this may or may not be relevant, but this error can also be caused by procedural language functions changing the current directory. See my other answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76653616/2239798